# hover not working in block level link

Tags: css, hover, anchor

HTML5 allows wrapping a block level in an anchor tag.
However it seems that as soon as the color of an selector (in the example `h4`) is previously declared, declaring a new link and hover color does not work.

```css
h4 {
    color: orange;
}

.test a:link, .test a:active, .test a:visited {
    color: green;
    display: inline-block;
}

.test a:hover {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
    <a href="#">
        <h4>Heading</h4>
        <p>This is the paragraph</p>
    </a>
</div>
```

You can also find this example at Codepen: http://codepen.io/Ixillion/pen/ouBrD

In this example the paragraph text has the correct link color (green) and hover color (red). The `h4` heading doesn't.
As soon as you take the `h4` declaration in the css away it works fine.  Unfortunately this simple solution is not possible in my project.
Is this a css bug or am I doing something wrong? Any help would be appreciated very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only changing the color of the anchor tag, not the header element. This is probably a CSS bug if this is allowed in HTML5 as I have not seen this. You could narrow your selector down `.test a:hover h4` or `.test a h4:hover` whichever works.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are changing the color of the `a` tag on hover, not the color of the `h4` tag. Since `h4` is closer to the text you want to change, the CSS for that tag overrides the CSS for your `a` tag.

Try the following code:

```
.test a:hover h4{
  color: red;
}
```

That is changing the color of `h4` when you hover over `a`.